# Hiding file extensions with .htaccess has no effect

Tags: .htaccess

My .htaccess-file looks like this:

```
############HTACCESS W4Y START############
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fabiansquinobal.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.fabiansquinobal.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
#############HTACCESS W4Y END#############
```

It´s laying in the root-directory of my webserver, but it has no effect on the filenames. Can you tell me if the code is valid?

Comment: How do you know, that it has no effect? What do you expect, when you do what? And what happens instead?

Comment: Maybe the root-directory of the webserver is not the document root directory? Or maybe `htaccess` files are not enabled?